# Классы в Андроид

Tags: java, android, классы

Создал свой класс. Если запустить приложение с таким кодом, то все ломается.

```
public class Heroes {

    Heroes [] id = new Heroes[1];
    String name;


    public Heroes(){
        id[0] = new Heroes();
        id[0].name = "asdf";
    }
}
```

Но стоит поменять на другое и все работает.

```
public class Heroes {

    Heroes [] id = new Heroes[1];
    String name;

    public Heroes(){}


    public Heroes(int a){
        id[0] = new Heroes();
        id[0].name = "asdf";
    }
}
```

Ну и конечно создавать тогда не `Heroes x = new Heroes();`а `Heroes x = new Heroes(любой число);`

Вопрос: создание классов под андроид отличается от той же JavaFX и обычной консоли? Потому что я первый раз с такой проблемой столкнулся. Среда разработки одна и та же.

Comment: Что именно означает "все ломается"?

Comment: `id[0] = new Heroes();` попахивает рекурсией. Причём вечной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Если запустить приложение с таким кодом, то все ломается

А вам ошибка `StackOverflowError` ни о чем не говорит?

В первом примере при вызове конструктора без параметров внутри него вызывается он же сам, и так до бесконечности:

```
public Heroes(){
    id[0] = new Heroes();//вызов Heroes(), который снова вызовет себя в первой строке и.т.д.
    id[0].name = "asdf";
}
```

Во втором же случае у вас из констуктора с параметром вызывается конструктор без параметров, который имеет пустое тело, соответственно никакого зацикливания не происходит и всё работает

Comment: не запускалось просто приложение. комплиятор не ругался. да, точно... в других похожих примеров мне нужны были другие конструкторы, а тут нет. все понял, спасибо!